# fade in/ fade out não é executado

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    alert("ready");
    $("#comentario").fadeIn(1000);
    $("#nome").fadeIn(2000);
    $("#foto").fadeIn(4000);

    $(".back").click(function () {
        $("#comentario").fadeout(1000);
        $("#nome").fadeout(2000);
        $("#foto").fadeout(4000);
    })


    $(".next").click(function () {
        $("#comentario").fadein(1000);
        $("#nome").fadein(2000);
        $("#foto").fadein(4000);
    })
})


</script>
```

Bom, vendo o código acima, preciso saber o que está errado, quando meu documento é iniciado, ele dá o fadein nas 3 ids ali apontadas(comentario,nome,foto). Porém, quando o botão é pressionado das classes(.next, .back) ele não faz o prometido...

**curiosidade:** o alert() é executado  apenas no inicio de cada função, não no meio, ou no final, exemplo:

```
$(".next").click(function(){
    alert("vai emitir a mensagem");
    $("#comentario").fadein(1000);
    $("#nome").fadein(2000);
    $("#foto").fadein(4000);
    })
})
```

mas se não for na primeira linha da função, ele não faz nada..

```
$(".next").click(function(){
    $("#comentario").fadein(1000);
    alert("não vai emitir a mensagem");
    $("#nome").fadein(2000);
    $("#foto").fadein(4000);
    })
})
```

estou usando a biblioteca Jquery,..
agradeço!

Comment: Nunca deixe de checar o console do browser ao executar seu JavaScript. É lá que são mostrados os erros.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O seu problema é apenas falta de atenção ao digitar ao funções `fadeIn()` e `fadeOut()`.

Por isso o seu alert não funcionava. Esperimente o firebug para firefox!

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log( 'document ready');
    $("#comentario").fadeIn(500);
    $("#nome").fadeIn(1000);
    $("#foto").fadeIn(1500);

    $(".out").click(function () {
        console.log( 'fadeOut');
        $("#comentario").fadeOut(500);
        $("#nome").fadeOut(1000);
        $("#foto").fadeOut(1500);
    })


    $(".in").click(function () {
        console.log( 'fadeIn');
        $("#comentario").fadeIn(500);
        $("#nome").fadeIn(1000);
        $("#foto").fadeIn(1500);
    })
})
```

```css
div{
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="" id="comentario" >
    comentario
</div>
<div class="" id="nome" >
    nome
</div>
<div class="" id="foto" >
    foto
</div>
<a class="out" href="#">fadeOut()</a>
<a class="in" href="#">fadeIn()</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

À parte do problema real da pergunta, que [o @mdma deu conta e respondeu](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/36960/129), aqui fica uma sugestão para optimizar o seu código.

Em vez de se repetir nos seletores, que consomem recursos cada vez que são chamados e são dificeis de manter (fácil trocar `fadeIn` por `fadein`), pode fazer assim, usando o [.fadeTo()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeto/):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var elementos = $("#comentario, #nome, #foto");
    fadeTo();
    $(".back").click(fadeTo);
    $(".next").click(fadeTo);

    function fadeTo(){
        var toggle = this.classList.contains('next') ? 1 : 0;
        elementos.each(function(i){
            $(this).fadeTo(Math.pow(2, i) * 1000, toggle);
        });
    }
});
```